# UIScrollView with wider UIView not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning to use `UIScrollView` to make several pictures could scroll horizontally. These images are programmatically added as a subview to a `UIView` within `UIScrollView`. The 'Scrolling enabled' is also set true. However, when I run the app, the `UIScrollView` cannot scroll.

Here is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollContentView: UIView!

    var imageViews = [UIImageView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageWidth: CGFloat = 200.0 / 768.0 * 1024.0

        for i in 1...3 {
            let image = UIImage(named: "image\(i)")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageViews.append(imageView)

            let x: CGFloat = CGFloat(i - 1) * (imageWidth + 10)
            scrollContentView.addSubview(imageView)
            print(imageView.frame)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: 200.0)
        }

        scrollContentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: imageWidth * 3 + 20.0, height: 200.0)

        scrollView.contentSize = scrollContentView.frame.size

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add some constraints on your `scrollContentView` ? Try to remove all of them, it should work like that.

Comment: @YannArmelin It works! But removing constraints will cause an error that says ''Scrollable content size is ambiguous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the `scrollContentView` in Interface Builder, create it programmatically.

Xcode won't complain anymore about missing contraints, and you will be able to play with the frame manually.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var scrollContentView: UIView!

    var imageViews = [UIImageView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollContentView = UIView()
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollContentView)

        let imageWidth: CGFloat = 200.0 / 768.0 * 1024.0

        for i in 1...3 {
            let image = UIImage(named: "image\(i)")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageViews.append(imageView)

            let x: CGFloat = CGFloat(i - 1) * (imageWidth + 10)
            scrollContentView.addSubview(imageView)
            print(imageView.frame)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: 200.0)
        }

        scrollContentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: imageWidth * 3 + 20.0, height: 200.0)

        scrollView.contentSize = scrollContentView.frame.size

    }

}
```